# How to handle azure access token between web api and angular apps without using MSAL.js

Tags: asp.net, angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am working on a project with asp.net web api in back and angular in front. I have set up normal login in my application. I need to add login with azure as well. How can I do azure login with MSAL along with normal login without using MSAL.js just using web Msal. I also have some example of azure signin with msal using MVC controller. Then how can I connect MVC and api sending access token to frontend application?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63222266/how-can-i-get-azure-ad-authentication-from-net-core-program-for-angular-app/63259142#63259142